# Execute dynamic SQL in Data Flow Task SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

Here is what i want to do:

I am selecting SQL scripts from a database and assigning these scripts to a variable in for each loop (imagine that all scripts have different columns). After that, I am trying to execute SQL scripts in Data Flow Task ODBC Source. I am using SQL_COMMAND @variable from Data Flow Task Properties. This option does not work. I guess it is not understanding dynamic columns. SSIS gives me a validation error.

Also, I tried to execute these scripts in Execute SQL Task from a variable. Again my source is ODBC. I assigned full result set to an object variable in Execute SQL Task but it gives me an error. As far as I know, there is an issue about ODBC. So, I can not assign full result set to an object variable in ODBC.

Do you guys have any idea? How can i execute these scripts in SSIS and get the result? I need to get the result and insert it to a destination table.

P.S: I can not use OLE DB connection because of the server issue. All scripts need to be executed in same environment.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS requires that the column metadata is both static and correct between all sources, transformation and destinations.  You cannot simply loop through a list of scripts and run the different results through the same data flow.

The only way you could achieve this is to use something like [Biml](http://www.bimlscript.com/) to build your packages for you programatically from your source scripts.  There are a couple free and paid ways to develop Biml, such as the free BIDSHelper and BimlExpress (Made by the creators of Biml: Varigence) add ins for Visual Studio or the paid BimlStudio (Also from Varigence).